# Salesforce formula including LongTextArea querying

Tags: formula

I'm trying to use the following formula:

```
TEXT([Case].Status) =  'Awaiting Input' &&
 ([Case].RecordType__c = 'rt'  &&  
 NOT ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE([Case].Workflow__c))
)
```

Where workflow__c is type of LongTextArea.

That formula seems to not execute the right results..
When reading on formulas I understood that LongTextArea not supported inside formulas?

Does it mean that I can't use `isChanged`, `IsBlank` etc on LongTextArea fields at all?

Can I workaround this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is an Apex trigger and a custom field `Is_Changed_Workflow__c` (checkbox).

Use the trigger (before update) to set the value to true when Workflow__c has changed and then use a final action in Process Builder to reset it to false once you've applied whatever actions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use longtextarea fields in formula fields. Though you can write trigger and make the field read only on the page layout. There is an idea to support longtextarea fields in formula. Please upvote. [success.salesforce.com](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhEAAS)